# Set a defaults for views in Ionic AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm learning Ionic framefork to develop an app.
I defined an abstract state like this:

```
.state('app', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/default.html"
  })
```

My default.html looks like this:

```
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <div ui-view="headerview"></div>
    <div ui-view="contentview"></div>
</ion-side-menu-content>
<div ui-view="menuview"></div>
```

And then I declared all my actual states

```
.state('app.contacts', {
    url: '/contacts',
    views: {
        'headerview': {
        templateUrl: "templates/common/header.html" ,
        controller: 'headerControllers'
        },

        'menuview': {
        templateUrl: "templates/common/menu.html"
        },

        'contentview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactControllers'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.partners', {
    url: '/partners',
    views: {
        'headerview': {
        templateUrl: "templates/common/header.html" ,
        controller: 'headerControllers'
        },

        'menuview': {
        templateUrl: "templates/common/menu.html"
        },

        'contentview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/partners.html',
        controller: 'partnerControllers'
        }
    }
})
```

This works like a charm, but I noted that header and menu views will be the same in almost all of my states! That's not very DRY. There is a way to define a default that I can overwrite when needed?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this is to create store your path in a variable and use it for all your state.

in the begining of your function make :

```
var defaultHeader = 'templates/common/header.html';
var defaultHeaderController = 'headerControllers';
var defaultMenu = 'templates/common/menu.html';
```

then during the init of your state you will be able to do :

```
.state('app.contacts', {
    url: '/contacts',
    views: {
        'headerview': {
        templateUrl: defaultHeader ,
        controller: defaultHeaderController
        },
        'menuview': {
        templateUrl: defaultMenu
        },

        'contentview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactControllers'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.partners', {
    url: '/partners',
    views: {
        'headerview': {
        templateUrl: defaultHeader ,
        controller: defaultHeaderController
        },
        'menuview': {
        templateUrl: defaultMenu
        },

        'contentview': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/partners.html',
        controller: 'partnerControllers'
        }
    }
})
```

Like that if you want to overwrite the default view you can.
And to update it you have only one place to modify the code.